# I need advice on whether to quit or not

Tags: quitting

I've been working at McDonalds for about a week now and to be perfectly honest I don't particularly like it. My colleagues are pretty nice give or take a few but they failed to train me properly and I am now being put in for retraining. Also the kitchen staff have been somewhat slow in putting out more food and the customers take it out on me. I'm also finding the job really stressful an it's only part time due to me still being at school (Year 12 in the UK) personally I don't handle stress really well and I get stressed enough at school without the stress of work and rude customers. I want to give it up but my mum told me to give it a little longer, however if I leave it much longer than I have to give two weeks notice which I really don't want to do. If I'm honest I'm more worried about telling my mum that I'm quitting, even though she knows I want to as I came home crying yesterday, than actually talking to my manager about it. Please help!

Comment: Why do you work? Do you have enough money without a job?

Comment: After one week - hang in for a few weeks at least?

Comment: I also had a job like this where they didn't train me properly and just threw me out in front of customers. It was completely miserable. Hang in there, see if you can make it a few weeks. It will get easier. If you do decide this job is too intense for you, you can look for a more low-key job, maybe at a clothing shop or grocery store, where the pace is a little more relaxed.

Comment: Unfortunately, you and the rest of your coworkers could do everything perfectly all the time and there will still be some customers who will be rude. Sometimes customers have a bad experience in your restaurant and that encourages them to be rude, and sometimes customers have a bad experience **before** they get to your restaurant and they are just rude to whomever is in front of them. This is not how things are at McDonald's, it's how things are everywhere all the time. One way I avoid getting stressed out is remember "It's just a hamburger". You're not going to crash an airplane or anything.

Comment: Its just a MacJob .Low pay ,Low self esteem,No future job in the service industry.Stick at it for a bit longer and politely leave.

Answer (score 20):

Kat, it can be difficult being new at any job.

Fast food restaurants can be particularly tough, until you get used to the pace of it. They are fast, customers want prompt service, and sometimes they don't care if you are new or not. I once owned a fast food restaurant with my family. It was even hard on me when I was new, and I was one of the owners!

Try to hang in there a while longer, Kat. That way, you'll get the training you need, and will certainly get more used to the flow of the work.

I find that avoiding stress isn't always the best approach. As you go through life you'll find that some things will be stressful - school, family events, work, etc. Dealing with the less pleasant and more stressful parts of life are just part of learning to be an adult. We all have to go through it, and we usually feel better when we learn to face these situations directly and overcome them, rather than always trying to avoid them.

Give it some more time. You'll be better for it no matter what you decide to do eventually.

And if you do decide you need to leave, find a new job first, then give your proper notice. You'll be showing yourself and others (particularly your mum) that you are becoming a responsible adult. I'll bet she'd be really proud about that.

Answer (score 4):

on the positive side your colleagues are mostly nice, and the job pays you money. Look at it as gaining valuable experience. You learn how to cope with colleagues and customers, which is a valuable experience for yourself, and gives you an advantage when you apply for the next job.

By far the most valuable experience will be how to handle *stress*. The secret of stress is that you create it yourself. It's not rude customers that cause stress, it's your own reaction to them. If anyone has to take their bad mood out on a 16 or 17 year old girl working at McDonalds, then your problem having a rude customer is nothing compared to the problem that customer has with their life. So when you have your next rude customer, try to be not annoyed or stressed but feel sorry for them. You are just starting out, you will be far ahead of them in a few years.